# kapt in Kotlin Multiplatform - src dirs not recognized by gradle and IDE by default

Tags: kotlin, dagger-2, kotlin-multiplatform, moshi, kapt

I have a Kotlin annotation processor library which generates some classes and writes them with

```
    FileSpec.builder(...)
        ...
        .build()
        .writeTo(processingEnv.filer)
```

The generated files end up in `build/generated/source/kapt/...`. They are only recognized by gradle if I add `kotlin.srcDir("${buildDir.absolutePath}/generated/source/kapt/")` to my `build.gradle.kts`.

It works the same way if I use `kapt.kotlin.generated` option - the path changes to `build/generated/source/kaptKotlin/...` but I still need to explicitly add the path to sources dir for the gradle to use these files during build process. Otherwise it's not only unrecognized by gradle, but also by Intellij.

Important note: my processor works in a Kotlin Multiplatform module.

I don't see necessity to include the generated source dirs with codegen libraries like `dagger` or `moshi` - they seem to just write to `processingEnv.filer` and everything works automagically.

So there must either be some additional configuration which makes it possible to omit the explicit `kotlin.srcDir...` or there is some limitation of KMM project. Any idea what the fix might be?

Comment: Hello, Michał! Could you please tell me if this problem is still relevant? If it does, please consider filing an issue at https://kotl.in/issue.

Comment: Sure, I filed an issue https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-50980, it's still relevant. @ArtyomDegtyarev :)